# background image not being responsive

Tags: html, css

The dev site is located at http://www.clhdesigns.com/cliwork/wintermeresod/about.php

The issue I'm having is if you take a look at the home page the background images scales perfectly while on the about us page it doesn't at all. What I'm looking for is a 100% scale down here is the code that I have.

```
<div id="main" class="about">
<div class="inner">
<div class="welcome_intro2">
  <h1>Growing Top Quality Sod</h1>
  <h2>for over 25 years</h2>
</div>
```

And now here is the corresponding CSS

```
#main { float:left; width:100%;   padding:1em 0 3em 0; color:#666;}

.about {
background: url("../images/banner3010.jpg") no-repeat;
height:582px;
width:100%;
}
```

What I'm looking for is to keep the height of the image in the desktop where it is but I need it to be 100% responsive. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean something like `background-size: 100%` ?

Comment: yes something like background size 100%

Comment: Like i see you used the answer in your website but you didn't marked the answer as correct. I know that you are new here but you should mark as correct because other users don't have to give other answer too when an correct and working answer is there :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look.

```
.about {
background: url("../images/banner3010.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
height:582px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a [SCREENSHOT](http://prntscr.com/c7ffih) of how it works. I have used the same code that has the image in the first page and this is what made it responsive. Check code below

```
.about {
    background: url("../images/banner3010.jpg") center center no-repeat;
    height:582px;
}
```

You can use `@media` queries for tablet and mobile phone image `height`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .about {
        height:300px; /*whatever height you want*/
    }
}
```